# Allow service to service call for API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I just want to allow my API Gateway to be called from a particular lambda function and my instance only. It should not be allowed to call from anywhere over the internet. Here is my resource policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-2:xxxxx",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "x.x.x.x"
                },
                "ArnNotLike": {
                    "aws:SourceARN": "arn of lambda function"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-2:xxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

Even though after adding source ARN I am still not allowed to call from my lambda function.

Comment: Why do you use public API gateway if you only want it to be called internally? Why not create private API which is specially developed by AWS for the use case you describe?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 conditions, unless the Lambda function is matching that CIDR range it will still not execute.

Answer (score 0):

Use [private API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html) instead of public.